# How do you get FFMPEG to change the aspect ratio from 16:9 back to 4:3 but NOT letterbox (unstretch)

Tags: video, ffmpeg

This is the opposite of the question that is usually posted. Many Youtube videos that claim to be "remastered" versions of old films are incorrectly rendered as 16:9 instead of 4:3 and are stretched so that circles appear to be ovals. This can be corrected by changing the aspect ratio in VLC from 16:9 to 4:3, but how can the original video be remuxed or reencoded so that it is restored to its correct and original shape?

Answer (score 6):

Try `-aspect`, which avoids re-encoding the video:

```
ffmpeg -i "$in_file" -c copy -aspect 4:3 "$out_file"
```

Answer (score 5):

Simply, scale it back to 4:3 and set a unit aspect ratio.

```
ffmpeg -i in -vf scale=ih*4/3:ih,setsar=1 -c:a copy out.mp4
```